# Bootstrap Select collides with JQuery virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, keyboard

This is a good one. Basically, I am using two libraries in particular to get what I want. Bootstrap select:

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

And JQuery virtual keyboard:

https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/

(Added the links in case someone finds them useful for their own stuff)

I use bootstral select because the queried data that appears as a selection group is quite large, as such it makes sense to add an input field utility in there to make it simpler for our users. We also require a virtual keyboard which is exactly the reason why we are adding the jquery plugin. The issue is that when we touch the select input and the keyboard comes out, whatever we type does not get filtered. Nor added, the keyboard thus far appears to work only on regular input text fields

In the simplest of forms, this is the code that I am using to generate the keyboard as well as to initialize the select picker:

```
let virtualK = ()=> {
    $('.buscame')
          .keyboard({
            layout: 'qwerty',
            position: {
              of : $(window),
              my : 'center bottom',
              at : 'center bottom',
              at2: 'center bottom'  
            }
          })
          .addTyping();
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').selectpicker({});
    $('#Transfer').selectpicker({});
    $('#Chofer').selectpicker({});
    $('#Transportista').selectpicker({});
    $('#localidad').selectpicker({});
    $('#Cliente').selectpicker({});

    // Initialize the keyboard
    virtualK();
  });
```

As for the select tag, the code reads like this:

```
<select name="Transfer" size="1" id="Transfer" class="form-control select-picker buscame" data-live-search="true" required onChange="javascript:OnChangeOperador()">
```

Another issue that I am facing is that If I try to run the JS code by passing `.buscame` as the identifier then the keyboard does not show up, wheras if I select the general identifier as `input` it works. The documentation for bootstrap select does not show any way to add an id for their automatically generated input boxes, so that seems to not be an option(if anyone knows otherwise do tell)

So, does anyone know of a way to make the virtual keyboard work on the inner search box of custom select? Or how to add an id to the generated input filter field?

EDIT:

I tried using

```
let virtualK = ()=> {
    $('input[role="textbox"]')
          .keyboard({
            layout: 'qwerty',
            position: {
              of : $(window),
              my : 'center bottom',
              at : 'center bottom',
              at2: 'center bottom'  
            }
          })
          .addTyping();
  }
```

But it does the same, the virtual keyboard opens up but whatever I type does not get filtered.

Took me a while because jsfiddle and jsbin were being funny, but here is the recreation of this issue:

https://codepen.io/AlecX4/pen/vJvmLb?editors=0000

Comment: Add a jsfiddle/snippet as a working example

Comment: @Dekel surely, let me finish writing it up

Comment: @Dekel added it! Sorry it took so long, got caught up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the value of the relevant input and trigger the `propertychange` of that input in order to tell the `bootstrap-select` that the input's value was change.

```
change: function(e, keyboard) {
    keyboard.$el.val(keyboard.$preview.val())
    keyboard.$el.trigger('propertychange')        
  }
```

Here is a an update to your codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvGpvz

Comment: Thank you Dekel, worked like a charm. I am reading on the documentation regarding the change function and how it works, but I am not being able to see how you made the connection to this. I guess I'll keep staring at the definition until it makes sense. Til then, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: let me know which/what part of the code you didn't understand :)

Comment: Well for example, the documentation for change states that the change callback is called on every keyboard interaction no mater the setting of the usePreview option. The usePreview (for what I can gather) changes depending on which input field is open(correct?) keyboard.$el refers to the keyboard input jquery object, so when you set the val to keyboard.$preview.val() you are changing the value to the focused input? I kind of get the code, If anything I am amazed at how you managed to find the things that you needed to help me solve this so quickly!

Comment: `keyboard.$preview.val()` takes the value from the `preview` input (not relevant to the focused one), `keyboard.$el.val(...` will set the value to the original input (because otherwise it will be set only when you click on the "accept" button. I couldn't find a way to make it set for every key). Hope this comment makes it clear :)